# The Recycle events on IIS are not being logged on Event Viewer

Tags: .net, iis

I am trying to register when my application pool is recycled. I edited my App pool configuration and change to True value all items on "Generate Recycle event log entry" on advance setting on my app pool.
When I make a manual recycle, the event is not logged on system log in Event viewer. 
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Recycling event log entries are in "System" log not in "Application". Are you looking at the right place ?

Comment: Yes, I am looking on right place, I am trying to locate the WAS source but they don't appear :(